# PHP stacking array in another using push

Tags: php, arrays, push

Could anyone explain me how to solve the following:

```
function GetSetClearForm(){

   $person = array('firstname' => $_POST["fname"], 'lastname' => $_POST["lname"],'age' => $_POST["age"] ,'city' => $_POST["city"] ,'zipcode' => $_POST["zcode"],'address' => $_POST["address"]);
   print_r($person);
   $personlist = array();
   array_push($personlist,$person);
   print_r($personlist);

   return $personlist;
}
```

When the `print_r($personlist);` has ran I get the following output:

```
 Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
       [firstname] => 2 
       [lastname] => 2 
       [age] => 2 
       [city] => 2 
       [zipcode] => 2 
       [address] => 2 
       ) 
    )
```

(filled in all textboxes with "2").

This is ok at this point, but whenever I fill in another one I get this output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
           [firstname] => 1 
           [lastname] => 1 
           [age] => 1 
           [city] => 1 
           [zipcode] => 1 
           [address] => 1 
           ) 
     )
```

(filled in all textboxes with "1").

So instead of creating another person on a new index (`index[1]`) it replaces `index[0]` with a new person and deletes the older one. I dont want it do delete it I want to get a list full of people. I think it has to do with the `array_push` but I am not sure I hope anyone could help me out here.

**EDIT:**

Added the index.php:

```
<form action="check.php" method="POST">
<table>
<tr><td>First name</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last name</td><td><input type="text" name="lname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Age</td><td><input type="text" name="age"></td></tr>
<tr><td>City</td><td><input type="text" name="city"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Zipcode</td><td><input type="text" name="zcode"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Adress</td><td><input type="text" name="address"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Added the check.php

```
<?php
include("functions.php");

$personlist = array();
$personlist[] = GetSetClearForm();
print_r($personlist);
?>
```

Comment: Read about variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You are stil re-iniializing person list. it will keep adding them to [0] each time the script runs. It is why I put them in the seesion. But as stated below, you might be better off saving each form entry to a database or file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using array_push you can use this:

```
$personlist = array();
$personlist[] = $person;
```

This way a new index is created every time you 'insert' a new value, in this case an array.

**EDIT:**

You need to declare and fill your $personlist array outside your function. That said:

```
function GetSetClearForm(){

   $person = array('firstname' => $_POST["fname"], 'lastname' => $_POST["lname"],'age' => $_POST["age"] ,'city' => $_POST["city"] ,'zipcode' => $_POST["zcode"],'address' => $_POST["address"]);
   print_r($person);
   return $person;
 }

 $personlist = array();
 $personlist[] = GetSetClearForm();
```

Comment: +1, actually, it is stated even in php manual: _*Note*:  If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] =  because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function._

Comment: unfortunately it is still placing a second (3rd,4th etc..) person array on index[0] of personlist causing the previous person to "dissolve".

Comment: After edit: still replaces it, Array (personlist) [0] fname = 1 lname = 2 etc....   adding second user, Array (personlist) [0] fname = 2 lname = 2 , person 1 is gone

Comment: @Niek Jonkman, Are you running the script after every POST action? If that's the case, the personlist array will always be declared as a new one.

Comment: So how do I add more people withouth running the script after every post? (I'm a beginner)

Comment: Ok, you have to save every person in a file if you are not using a database. An XML would be the best option.

Comment: @NiekJonkman you sohuld accept (checking the "V" mark near) the Answer that helped you in your problem. It's a way to say "thanks" here on S.O.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are re-creating person list each time the function is called. Maybe you can solve it like this:

```
//Create your person list some where else and keep it alive.
//Like in a session? 
session_start();


//Then give your keep alive array to your function each time.
function GetSetClearForm(){

$person = array('firstname' => $_POST["fname"], 'lastname' => $_POST["lname"],'age' => $_POST["age"] ,'city' => $_POST["city"] ,'zipcode' => $_POST["zcode"],'address' => $_POST["address"]);
print_r($person);

return $person;
}


$_SESSION['personlist'][] = GetSetClearForm() ;   
print_r( $_SESSION['personlist']);
```